# Как проверить дату в формате ISO, что она лежит в неком промежутке, на сервере?

Tags: javascript, node.js, дата, datetime

Подскажите, как проверить дату в формате ISO,что она лежит в промежутке между сегодняшней датой и некой датой в будущем на сервере?
как учесть все тайм зоны

например

21:57
вторник, 22 мая 2018 г. (GMT+3)
Москва

0:57
среда, 23 мая 2018 г. (GMT+6)
Омск, Омская область

эти даты одинаковые

а также время. если сегодняшний день, то не меньше текущего времени

то есть юзер где-нибудь в  Омске отправил 21 мая 21:05, то мне на бэке надо как бы сравнить эта дата и это время находятся в промежутке между сегодняшней датой и 21.09.18 например и еще если это сегодня, то еще проверить время. больше ли время его текущего времени или нет. если он ввел 21:50 и отправил на бэк, а сейчас у него 21:55, то это время уже невалидно

На бэк приходит дата в формате ISO
Узнать текущую дату на бэке
Сравнить, что пришедшая дата лежит в промежутке между сегодняшним числом и 21.09.18 и если сегодняшнее,то сравнить время которое пришло. Оно должно быть не меньше времени текущего у юзера.
Если юзер отправил 21:50 у себя, а сейчас у него 21: 56, то это невалидно

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Так Вы же сами говорите, что у Вас даты в формате ISO, почему не сделать просто что-нибудь вроде `d = new Date(ISODateString)`, и потом сравнивать с чем угодно? Неоднозначности-то возникнуть не должно.

Comment: а текущую дату как я узнаю? если я просто сделаю new Date() на сервере, то это нормально?

Comment: а как перевести дату 21.09.18 в ISO? 
еще и время нужно учитывать

Comment: То есть алгоритм такой:

1. получаю дату с фронта, и делаю new Date(ISODateString)
2. получаю текущую дату на сервере. Просто new Date()
3. перевожу '21.09.18' в new Date() на сервере
3. с помощью moment или date-fns  сравниваю лежит ли в промежутке между new Date и 21.09.18

как быть со временем?

Comment: как мне первести на сервере 21.09.18 в ISO?я же переведу относительно того где у  меня сервер,а не местного времени

Comment: + надо учитывать что если это сегодня,то проверять местное введенное время, не меньше ли оно времени которое на данный момент местное сейчас